Firebase cloud storage ( for projects)
I'm working on a new project and was planning to use Firebase Storage to handle file uploads. In some of my previous projects, I was able to use Firebase Storage for free under the Spark Plan for development and testing purposes. However, this time, when I try to set it up, it's asking me to upgrade to a paid plan even though I haven’t uploaded a single file yet.
Is there a way to use Firebase Storage for free during development, or has Firebase changed its policies for new projects?


From 30th Oct 2024, Your Firebase project must be on the pay-as-you-go Blaze pricing plan.
You can check the updated policy here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/start#before-you-begin
This is still free & available same as before, but Blaze plan is required to access this feature.

Means there is no way to use storage for free ( as a student)

It's free like the same as the previous but required Blaze plan.

This is indeed correct: using Cloud Storage requires that your project is on a paid plan nowadays, but then it does still have a free tier. Also see my post here https://www.threads.net/@frankpuf/post/DBjSan0M36v/-cloud-storage-on-firebase-free-plan-is-going-awayfrom-october-30-itll-no-longer and the FAQ on https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/faqs-storage-changes-announced-sept-2024
